# wp_head is not fired from the hook I have used in my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I am a bit confused. I use `https://github.com/idleberg/php-wordpress-vite-assets` for using Vite's assets in my WordPress plugin.

I have used this:

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_loaded', [$this, 'testinit']);
}

public function testinit() {
    $basePath = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__);
    $manifest = $basePath."dist/manifest.json";
    $entryPoint = "index.js";

    $viteAssets = new WordpressViteAssets($manifest, $basePath);
    $viteAssets->addAction($entryPoint);
}
```

Inside of `add_action` the script does this:

```
add_action('wp_head', function () use ($entries) {
            foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                $scriptTag = $this->getScriptTag($entry);
```

But the script is not included in my head. When I call `getScriptTag` initially, instead of `addAction` I get a tag...

When I add a `die` statement before the foreach, it's not called. So it seems that the action for wp_head is not fired. I tried it also to use in my initial hook instead of `wp_loaded` other hooks like `admin_init`, `scripts_loaded` etc. But it seems I can not call wp_head inside of these hooks.

Does anybody know why and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I need to use `admin_head`, because `wp_head` it not fired in the backend of WordPress.